# luaj doesn't find .so modules

Tags: lua, torch, luaj

I've written a GUI in Java and use a lua-script to calculate some values for images  with a neural network. Therefore the lua-script requires some modules from torch7. 
I got so far that it finds the modules which have a init.lua file. However,  it fails when a module only has a .so file. The module is required in one of the init.lua files.
Before I require the modules in the script i set the new package.path and the package.cpath to LUA_PATH and LUA_CPATH because luaj only used the default path which didn't work.

I think this a LuaJ problem because when I run the script in the terminal with lua script_name.lua it works fine.

```
package.path = package.path .. ';/home/user/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1
/?.lua;/home/user/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/?/init.lua;/home/user/torch
/install/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/home/user/torch/install/share/lua/5.1
/?/init.lua;./?.lua;/home/user/torch/install/share/luajit-2.1.0-
beta1/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/?.lua;/usr/local/share/lua/5.1
/?/init.lua'

package.cpath = '/home/user/torch/install/lib/?.so;/home/user/.luarock
/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;/home/user/torch/install/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;./?.so;
/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/?.so;/usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/loadall.so'

require 'torch'
require 'nn'
require 'image'
```

The error message is as follows:

```
exception in thread "main" org.luaj.vm2.LuaError: @/home/user/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/paths/init.lua:1 module 'libpaths' not found: libpaths
no field package.preload['libpaths']
libpaths.lua
/home/user/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/libpaths.lua
/home/user/.luarocks/share/lua/5.1/libpaths/init.lua
/home/user/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/libpaths.lua
/home/user/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/libpaths/init.lua
./libpaths.lua
/home/user/torch/install/share/luajit-2.1.0-beta1/libpaths.lua
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/libpaths.lua
/usr/local/share/lua/5.1/libpaths/init.lua
no class 'libpaths'
```

I call the script from my java program:

```
public ScoreImage(){

    G_ = JsePlatform.standardGlobals();
    //G_.get("dofile").call( LuaValue.valueOf(changePath_));
    G_.get("dofile").call( LuaValue.valueOf(script_));

}
```

I use lua 5.1 because some of the problems where solved by changing from lua 5.2 to lua 5.1. I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and luaj 3.0.1.

I really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that LuaJ does not have the ability to load dll files and so files.
You may want to look into jnlua:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/jnlua/

Comment: Same problem with jnlua, the issue might be that torch uses luajit not lua, which from what I read is not compatible with jnlua.